# How to support HTML formatting tags within a custom tag?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, tags

I need assistance over how to incorporate HTML and CSS formatting tags for text within a custom tag.

**Scenario:** To view formatted text within `<value>...</value>` tag.
I have to provide the end user with an "Error body", with following fields to fill:

```
<data name="ErrorTitle.Text">
<data name="ErrorLogTime.Text">
<value> Error text here </value>
```

**Requirement:**
This `<value>` tag should support `<b>,<i>,<u>,<p class="formattedparagraph">` with text.

I have tried to use these tags but I receive the parser error as follows:

[image]

Comment: The parser was highlighting that class names should be in quotes `class="MsoNormal"`

Comment: you could use Literal control to show a string that contains Html tags as it is without parsing.